# load widgets after loading conten

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

What am doing is writing wizards using existing forms and list views. we want to combine these forms in single page. here is a script we have used to get form from url then called function to bind widgets. first line is loading content of form but bindWidgets is not working. While bindWidgets is working on preloaded content which is default loaded with page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#template_form").load("/push_templates/pushtemplate/create/ #zform");
        bindWidgets();
    });
</script>
```

Do we need to wait for load, as it seems that 2nd line is executed prior to content loaded. How can we go to wait stat or better way to call bind function after load complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#template_form").load("/push_templates/pushtemplate/create/ #zform", function() {
           bindWidgets();
        });

    });
</script>
```

You can see demo here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/39TuM/)**

Comment: +1 for prompt answer, Can you plz tell me how can I change id of form in loaded content, like from zform to myform

Comment: `zform` is the id of element of loaded content. You want to change id of it?

Comment: Ok, why do you want to change id?

Comment: I am loading forms from different urls, they may conflict, So I want to give them local names.

Comment: You need to change them in this service `/push_templates/pushtemplate/create/`. In this controller or service, you can replace form ids to ones you want